# Weblogic Management Exception

Tags: java, servlets, weblogic11g

I have been trying to deploy my Java Servlet on Oracle weblogic 11g, but getting this exception, when I try to start it after deploying my war.

> weblogic.management.ManagementException: [Deployer:149001]No
>   application named 'XXXX' exists for operation start.

Please suggest what am I missing.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same issue while deploying application through weblogic console. I did the following steps:

1. Cleared cache, stage, tmp from  server path.
2. Removed the application from target.
3. Restarted Managed and Admin servers.
4. And installed it again .

It worked!

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to resolve this by fully restarting WebLogic (i.e., restarting the Admin server.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same. There is an error during deploying.

I tried everything by steps:

- Restarted Admin sever
- Restarted managed servers
- Uninstall application and then install it again.

It works.